# com add-ins before outlook 2010 and after outlook 2010

Tags: .net, com, outlook, ms-office, add-in

what are the changes made for COM addin before outlook 2010(i.e., outlook 2000/2003/2007) and after 2010(i.e., outlook 2010/2013/2016).

I am asking this question because I have an outlook com addin that is working fine for 2000/2003/2007 but not working in 2010 and 2013.

please explain.

thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

While the Outlook Object Model was extended with each subsequent model, the COM addin model (IDTEXtensibility2) has not changed since Outlook 2000 (when it was introduced). What exactly does not work?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply actually I have a COM addin that is not all showing in the outlook-2010/2013 addins tab(also checked disabled and inactive addin catagories) but, This addin is working fine in 2000, 2003 and 2007

Comment: Did you check the relevant registry entries are set? What is the bitness of Outlook?